# plotly dash layout with dbc.col and dbc.row

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Hey im new to this boostrap. I want to make layout like this

[image]

but I don't know how. Instead if I use this simple code

```
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content])]),
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content])]),
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content])])
```

it turns out like this

[image]

I only need the layout code, like the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is you are declaring 3 rows in the first row you have 4 columns in the second have 3 columns and in the third row you have 2 columns

You should try to declare something like this

```
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([dbc.Row([content]),dbc.Row([content])]),dbc.Col([dbc.Row([content]),dbc.Row([content])]),dbc.Col([content]),
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content])])
```